# Tamanho da string no PL/SQL

Tags: sql, pl-sql

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TamanhoString(texto char(100))
 RETURN NUMBER IS tamanho NUMBER;
 BEGIN
    tamanho := LENGTH(texto);
    RETURN tamanho;
 END TamanhoString;
```

Preciso criar uma função que receba um texto como parâmetro e retorne seu tamanho. O código tá dando o seguinte erro:

Erro: PLS-00103: Encontrado o símbolo "(" quando um dos seguintes símbolos era esperado:     := ) , default varying caractere grande O símbolo ":=" foi substituído por "(" para continuar.

Comment: Você esta reinventando a roda! Basta usar o Length diretamente na sua aplicação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haviam alguns erros na escrita da sua função, corrigindo ficou:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TamanhoString (texto IN CHAR)
RETURN NUMBER AS
    tamanho NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        tamanho := LENGTH(texto);
    RETURN tamanho;
END;
```

Comment: Só um ponto que vale a pena a discurssão, sugiro que utilize `INTEGER` ao invés de `NUMBER` pois faz mais sentido para essa função